# automorphism of the structure

Tags: logic

I have to prove that the only automorphism of the structure $(\mathbb{Q}, \cdot, S)$ (where $S$ is a successor function) is the identity.

My question is: am I allowed to use that, since we have multiplication and we need neutral element, for any automorphism $h$, $h(1)=1$? I mean, is $(\mathbb{Q}, \cdot, S)$ really the same as $(\mathbb{Q}, 1, \cdot, S)$?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: "Successor function" is not a very good name for the function $x\mapsto x+1$ defined on the rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h$ be an automorphism of the structure $(\Bbb{Q}, \cdot, S)$ (comprising the rational numbers, the multiplication function $x \cdot y = xy$ and the "successor" function $S(x) = x + 1$). Now $0$ is characterised by the property that $0 \cdot x = 0$ for every $x \in \Bbb{Q}$, but then:

$$h(0) \cdot x = h(0) \cdot h(h^{-1}(x)) = h(0 \cdot h^{-1}(x)) = h(0)$$
 for every $x \in \Bbb{Q}$, so that $h(0)$ satisfies the characterising property of $0$ and hence $h(0) = 0$. Now using $h(S(0)) = S(h(0))$, you have, by induction, that $h(x) = x$ for every $x$ in $\Bbb{N}$. Using the fact that $x = y - 1$ iff $y = S(x)$ (which is equivalent to $h(y) = S(h(x))$) you get that $h(x) = x$ for every $x \in \Bbb{Z}$. Finally, assuming $y \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $z \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}$, you can use the fact that $x = \frac{y}{z}$ iff $y = x\cdot z$ (which is equivalent to $h(y) = h(x) \cdot h(z)$) to get that $h(x) = x$ for every $x \in \Bbb{Q}$.

In passing, you have also shown that an automorphism of $(\Bbb{Q}, \cdot, S)$, is also an automorphism of $(\Bbb{Q}, 1, \cdot, S)$. You are allowed to use this fact, but only after you have proved it $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, if I have another task now (connected to this one), where i have to show that some set is definable without parameters, can I use $1$ as a individual constant or will it be a parameter?

Comment: $1$ is definable in the structure, so you should be able to work as if it was a constant in the signature. But without seeing the exact problem you are trying to solve, I can't say for certain. Why don't you see how you get on and ask another question if you are unsure about your solution?